# Determine the product type in WooCommerce - Fatal error: Call to a member function is_type() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am facing this issue.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null

Will someone help me in this regard.

Here is the code I use.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'sione_change_cart_item_name_and_price', 10, 1 );
function sione_change_cart_item_name_and_price( $cart ) {
    global $product;
    
    // Get new items names from WC_Session
    $session_data = (array) WC()->session->get( 'new_item_names' );
    //$sku_data = (array) WC()->session->get( 'product_sku' );
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        
        
        if($product->is_type( 'simple' )) {
            $item_names = $product->get_short_description();
        } else {
            $item_names = $cart_item['data']->get_name() .", ". $cart_item['data']->get_attribute('color'). "," . $cart_item['data']->get_attribute('gender') . " (Product SKU: " . $cart_item['data']->get_sku() . ")";
        }
        // If item name doesn't exist in WC_Session for this cart item, we do it
        if( ! isset($session_data[$cart_item_key]) ) {
            $session_data[$cart_item_key] = $item_names;
            WC()->session->set( 'new_item_names', $session_data );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the product type in the following way

```php
function sione_change_cart_item_name_and_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' )) {
            echo 'Simple = ' . $product_id . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Else = ' . $product_id . '<br>';          
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'sione_change_cart_item_name_and_price', 10, 1 );
```